# 3D Rotation Decomposition?

Tags: geometry, 3d, rotations

I have a 3D local `xyz coordinate system` placed in a `world ENU (East-North-Up) coordinate system`.

The current relationship between them is shown as follows:

[image]

As shown, the angle $\theta$ is known. `z-axis` is vertical to `Up-axis` and thus lies on the `EN-plane`.

Now, I rotate the `xyz coordinate system` clockwise (seen from above) around `Up-axis` by an angle $\alpha$. During the rotation, `z-axis` is always kept on the `EN-plane`. $\theta$ is also kept as constant.

After the rotation, the position is as follows:

[image]

**My Question:**

Given $\theta$, how can I decompose the rotation around `Up-axis` $\alpha$ into two rotations around `x-axis` and `y-axis`?

What are their relationships?

Comment: You could have entirely avoided posting the photos at the same time being more clear about the problem. What i understood is that there are two co-ordinate systems and one of them is getting rotated. A typical confusion that arises here is your statement z-axis is vertical to up-axis. We cant say such things for two axes. You might have meant z-axis is perpendicular EN plane in which UP-axis lies. So to frame your query correctly i might say you need to rotate the xyz co-ordinate system in a uvw system such that z-axis is always on the horizontal v=0 plane and angle between v nd y is constant.

Comment: @MukeshKamath  But during the rotation, z-axis is NOT always perpendicular to a particular plane. All we can say is that it ALWAYS perpendicular to Up-axis, isn't it?

Comment: z-axis being perpendicular to Up-axis implies that it is lies in the EN plane(horizontal, Sorry for the goof up). This is so because both E and N axes are always perpendicular to Up-axis. An ENU coordinate system means all three are perpendicular to each other. Try out learning about change in coordinate systems in this link=> https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/alternate_bases/change_of_basis/v/lin-alg--changing-coordinate-systems-to-help-find-a-transformation-matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You describe a conversion between the rotation of a rigid object (or coordinate frame, i.e. the three pens in your first picture) around an axis (in your case, the blue line, corresponding to the normalised vector $b = (1/\sqrt3,1/\sqrt3,1/\sqrt3)$, so you rotate $\theta$ around the vector $b$; for that exist an expression given by:
$$R = \mathcal{I}_3\cos\theta+(1-\cos\theta)bb^T+[b]_{\times}\sin\theta,$$
that I took from [this Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Rotation_matrix_.E2.86.94_Euler_axis.2Fangle)

After that you want to take the matrix $R$ and decomposed to its [Euler angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles), notice that there's many options, yet you want the rotations around X and Y, so rotation around $Z$ it's an identity matrix according to your photos.

To decompose your rotation around axis $b$, you can use the expressions suggested in the Wikipedia entry for Euler angles.

I hope it helps :)